# Can Any one help on these box refresh token scripts?

Tags: php, curl, oauth-2.0, token

Can you please tell me, after executing this also I am not getting proper response.

**MY script**

```
$cmd="curl https://api.box.com/oauth2/token \ -d 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=uuuuuuuuu&client_id=uuuuuuu&client_secret=uuuuuuu' \ -X POST"; exec($cmd,$result);
```

**response**

```
Array ( [0] => {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"} )
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16740221/8057078) the box.net documentation lacks of the information that the `Content-Type` of requests for OAuth needs to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

So try to add an `-H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` at the end of your cURL request.

The cURL documentation states that the [parameter `-d`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d) already sets `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. But just according to other answers I found on Stack Overflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16740221/8057078), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17656501/8057078), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15437829/8057078)) trying to set the Content-Type manually could specifically help with the box.net OAuth API.